# How to solve numerically or analytically this Partial Differential Equation?

Tags: boundary-conditions, differential-equations

:D

I'm modeling a problem of ecology with PDEs, So I gotta solve numerically this Reaction-Diffusion Partial Differential Equation

$$
\frac{\partial u(t,x,y)}{\partial t}=D\Big( \frac{\partial^{2}u(t,x,y)
}{\partial x^{2}} +\frac{\partial^{2}u(t,x,y)
}{\partial y^{2}}\Big)+r\ u(t,x,y) \,\, ,
$$
where $D$ is the diffusion coeficient and the $r$ is a reaction coefficient or born rate (both constants). My boundary conditions are:

$$
\frac{\partial u(t,0,y)}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial u(t,x,0)}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial u(t,a,y)}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial u(t,x,b)}{\partial y}=0 \,\, ,
$$

and my inicial condition is:

$$
u(0,x,y)=u_{0}\delta (x) \,\, ,
$$

Where $\delta (x)$ is the Dirac Delta Function. I'm not able to solve this equation numerically yet, so how could I solve this equation numerically? (I'm not very sure about the boundary conditions, if there's something worong with them, feel free to tell me.)

More information:

The system is the following - I have an rectangular area where wasn't any animal there. I've inserted $u_{0}$ animals able to reproduce over this area. Assuming that there's not flux of animals on the boundaries i wanna know the dispersion of the population over this rectangular area.

How could I find the solution of that PDE and what's the solution for these boundary conditions?

Thank you for supporting!

Comment: I believe the only explicit solutions can be given by series (google "Series solutions to PDEs"). If you want a numerical approximation, Id recommend you to google "Finite Difference Methods for PDEs" or something like this. There is a problem though: you must replace the delta for some other (well behaved) function, so that you can use numerical methods. Finally, if you want an approximate analytic solution, you can take $a,b\to\infty$, in which case the solution is a gaussian profile.

Comment: @qftishard Yes, I was searching things about FDM, but it still is hard to find material for three variables.

Comment: Try "finite difference method 2D heat equation". The few first results look nice to me. Bear in mind this kind of numerical calculations are not easy if you are not used to numerical methods in general. On the other hand, there is a lot of software that will do the calculations for you, such as Matlab, Mathematica, etc. (also, there are routines online for this kind of jobs through c++, Java, etc. choose the language you prefer)

Comment: @WaynerKlën What do you mean "hard to find material for three variables"? I regularly solve chemically reacting Navier-Stokes with 300 variables using finite volume or finite difference methods.

Comment: @tpg2114 300 variables? really? I am very curious about this! What kind of problems are you working on? Do you use a regular computer? (I thought no desk computer could ever handle more that 10 variables or so)

Comment: @qftishard Thank you mate, I'll search your suggestion! :D

Comment: @tpg2114 I mean that I don't use to solve numerically this kind of equations, So when I did my research, it was hard to find examples with two spatial and one temporal coordinates.

Comment: @qftishard Large eddy simulations of turbulent, chemically reacting flows. I also worked on shock-to-detonation transition in condensed phase explosives and the transmission of the blast wave into the surrounding air. And no, definitely not regular computers -- we have several in-house clusters and access to many of the HPC machines at the DoD and national labs.

Comment: @WaynerKlën So not 3 variables but 3 coordinates... Since your equation doesn't have mixed derivatives (no $\partial x \partial y$ or $\partial x \partial t$ etc., the way you do the finite difference in space for $y$ is identical to the one for $x$. So it's easy to take a 1D finite difference expression and make it 2D or 3D (usually).

Comment: @tpg2114 Oh, I didn't think this way, I'll try your suggestion! Thank you! :D